# Windows Store Apps difference between Contracts and Extensions?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Can someone provide me an easy explanation of the difference between Contracts and Extensions in Windows Store Apps?

I have read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx, however, in some of the examples it isn't clear why one is a Contract and not an Extension and vice-versa.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "extend" a native function of Windows 8, like taking pictures or picking files - then your app is an "extension". It is more a category of apps based on their function. Contracts, in contrast, are just leveraging the charms and device capabilities. //End

To summarize:

- Many apps will use contracts.
- Few (very few?) apps will be extensions.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A contract is like an interface with the common windows 8 charm bar features such as share & search. 
You can make you app available to either provide to, or receive from these contracts.

An extension is where you might say, my app id used as a third part component, or as the link suggests says your app handles files of a particular extension and presents itself as a handler perhaps for that file type

Answer (score 0):

A contract is an agreement to consume and/or supply data in a specific format, often between apps as is the case with the Share contract. Contracts result in activations and are most often invoked directly from the Charms Bar (Search, Share, Settings, PlayTo) or the Start Menu (Launch).

An extension is an agreement between your app and the operating system. It is a way to extend the OS functionality with your app. AutoPlay for example allows the OS to launch your app when an item of a particular type is selected. Camera Settings will allow you to customize the camera settings provided by the OS when the user is configuring the camera.

So in general I think of contracts as app-app or app-user and extensions as app-OS, but it is obvious some are gray areas (like File Picker, I would consider that more an extension than a contract, but it is categorized as a contract).

Comment: I agree. There are some grey areas.